# Homophone Riddle 10

Tags: riddle, word

```
It is everything you hear,
And everything you say,
It is also permission to do something,
But they both sound the same,
And you can be ________ to say something ________
```

Just to clarify, the blanks are where the pair of homophones go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's

> Allowed and aloud

Everything I have heard has been

> aloud

as has everything I have said.*

When you have permission to do something,

> you are allowed to do it.

*

> Well, except for the things I have said in my head.  But the voices tell me not to talk about that!  8-)

Comment: Yes! Can you add how it matches the lines?